# Place at one's head

Tags: ramayana

I am currently reading Ramayana (a retelling by Krishna Dharma das, from here). There's a passage there that I found confusing:

> The distraught queen [Kaushalya] said to Bharata, “You may now enjoy this kingdom stripped of all its enemies. Surely You hankered for the sovereignty and now Your mother has fully secured it for You. The cruel Kaikeyi has sent away my son as an ascetic. She should now send me away as well. Otherwise **I shall place at my head the sacrificial fire** and, followed by Sumitra, proceed happily along the road taken by Rāma. In any event I cannot remain here any longer.”

What does Kaushalya mean here by "place at my head the sacrificial fire"? My immediate interpretation was that she wanted to enter the funeral pyre of her husband, but then that wouldn't be "proceeding along the road taken by Rama", since Rama didn't die but was exiled to the forest. Or does this mean simply bowing to the fire and following Rama in exile?

(I reposted this question here from English Language Learners because it doesn't seem to gain any traction here)